# Block-level linking issue woth ie7

Tags: css, html

Hello
I am trying to use block level linking in a html5 specified document. But when I have an img inside a div and the div has a width, the img is not clickable in ie7.

Any solution to this?

I get an error when I try to post the html but I hope you get the idea.

HTML
a --> div --> img

css
div {width:140px;height:70px;}

Comment: could you post the html? is the <img> within a link / or JS event?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the `div` element for any special reason?

You can turn `a` into a block-level element using the `display: block` property and assign it the dimensions that you want.

Probably what is happening is that the `div` is terminating the `a` prematurely since in pre-HTML5, you were not allowed to nest a block-element with an `a`.

Remember, IE7 is not HTML5 compliant, so it behaves like HTML4.1 with any IE7 behavior/quirks/bugs.

Comment: +1 `display: block` seems to be the best solution here, the `div` needs to go